# En el momento que intento hacer la asignaciones de columnas en el OLE BD Command estas columnas no me aparecen, SQL Comand Estoy utilizando un SP

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Error en Data Flow Task [OLE DB Command [142]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Error de sintaxis o infracción de acceso".

Answer (score 0):

Si utiliza el proveedor ***Microsoft OLE DB*** para DB2, debe tener instalado para poder aplicar este hotfix Host Integration Server 2009.

Concretamente si quieres [saber más](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/topic/revisi%C3%B3n-mensaje-de-error-cuando-utiliza-el-proveedor-ole-db-para-db2-para-importar-datos-timestamp-de-db2-en-sql-server-mediante-el-uso-de-ssis-la-parte-fraccionaria-del-valor-temporal-proporcionado-desborda-la-escala-del-par%C3%A1metro-de-sql-server-correspondiente-o-de-la-columna-1355f021-c512-2fda-e404-ccaadf262766)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).